# Responsive Website Design No Longer Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on converting a site to a RWD (Not Rear wheel drive) and have suddenly run into a problem.

As part of my diagnosis, I tried backtracking in my css file so that the only change to mobile.css is the color of the background from #000 to #FFFso I can see when a change takes effect but I can't get it to switch style sheets.

Here's the tags I have in order within my head section

```
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/about.html">

<!-- no-rss -->

<title>About Me and How to Contact Me</title>

<meta name="Description" content="About Me and How to Reach Me with Questions, Comments or Suggestions.">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="support-files/mobile.css"/>

<?php include 'z-end-of-head.php'; ?> //This houses the standard style sheet along with GA code etc

</head>
```

Here's the page: http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/about.html

If anyone could share with me why the site no longer switches between style sheets I'd be most appreciative as I have tried moving tags around and the works but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Iv'e tried everything now. Including checking and rechecking to make sure there are no misspellings or the sort, yet nothing works? Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: move the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="support-files/mobile.css"/>` to just before `</head>` i.e. after all the other CSS files are added by PHP.

Comment: What Mauro said, plus you have two definitions for meta viewport, for some reason. Also, use max-width and not max-device-width for the media query since you have set width=device-width.

Comment: It could be that relative urls are wrongly setup, instead try the following href: http:// www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/support-files/mobile.css But remove the space between http:// and url

Comment: Hello again everyone, I apologize for my having to step away but I'm back. I'd like to thank everyone for your help and I'm gonna try to address each contributor's comments.
Mauro I moved the link to just before </head> as you suggested and it seems to be now working on the Android device which I'm physically holding (Not using online simulator), yet I the desktop version never switches upon scrunching the window down tight and narrow.
@IanDevlin Huge Thanks for pointing this out. I forgot I had placed this in an include file. I have since removed it from about.html

Comment: Attention Everyone, After following @Mauro 's advice, the responsive nature seems to work on a mobile device but not when resizing a desktop version. Even using Chrome's "Incognito" mode

Comment: @IanDevlin I somehow missed the part about: Also, use max-width and not max-device-width for the media query since you have set width=device-width. Please do allow me to ask: Where do I have width=device-width?? Is this a best practice? Maybe I should start anew at: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html

Comment: Also, Could someone tell me where meta viewport should be? "Ideally"

Comment: if the question is answered you should accept the correct answer.  your additional question would best be asked as a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="support-files/mobile.css"/>` to just before `</head>` i.e. after all the other CSS files are added by PHP.

Comment: Ah Ha!! Now it seems to be working on a mobile device (In my left hand) but the desktop version at my right hand is still not switching style sheets. I'll try clearing browser cache and I have a cple questions I'd like to ask but I must leave temporairly.

Comment: Hi Mauro, I thank you for your help with showing me where to place the link. If you wouldn't mind, Could you(or anyone else) please assist me with my layout? I've been struggling with this all day and it's probably incredibly simple to you guys but I can't seem to crack it. If anyone wouldn't mind showing me how I could get the NavColumn and ExtraColumn in my layout to sit in their respective places I'd be most appreciative. Here's a sample URL: http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/about.html